# python combinations of split of list

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, combinatorics

Given two input arguments:

`x`: `<list>` like `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

`splits`: `<list>` of `int` representing the number and the length of the splits, like `[1, 2, 1]`. It means that the list must be split in 3, the 1st one contains 1 element, the 2nd contains 2 elements and the 3rd split contains 1 elements

I need a function that returns all the possible combinations of the splits, eg:

`def get_combos(x, splits): ...`

`>>> get_combos([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1])`

```
[(0,), (1, 2), (3,)]
[(0,), (1, 3), (2,)]
[(0,), (2, 3), (1,)]
[(1,), (0, 2), (3,)]
[(1,), (0, 3), (2,)]
[(1,), (2, 3), (0,)]
[(2,), (0, 1), (3,)]
[(2,), (0, 3), (1,)]
[(2,), (1, 3), (0,)]
[(3,), (0, 1), (2,)]
[(3,), (0, 2), (1,)]
[(3,), (1, 2), (0,)]
```

Input will **always** meet these conditions:

- `min(splits) >= 1` --> There is always an element in the split
- `sum(splits) == len(x)` --> All the elements in `x` are taken

What is the best way to do it recursively?

Comment: why would you want to do this recursively? also its usually more likely to get an answer if you have already attempted this ... here is a hint ... given a list make the exact splits specified ... start by making a function that simply takes a list  and some split lengths and returns a new split list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def combos(a, b, c = []):
   if not a or not b:
      yield [*map(tuple, c)]
   else:
      for x, y in enumerate(a):
         if not c or len(c[-1]) == b[0]:
            yield from combos(a[:x]+a[x+1:], b[1:] if c else b, c+[[y]])
         else:
            yield from combos(a[:x]+a[x+1:], b, [*c[:-1], c[-1]+[y]])

print(list(combos([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1])))
```

Output:

```
[[(0,), (1, 2), (3,)], [(0,), (1, 3), (2,)], [(0,), (2, 1), (3,)], [(0,), (2, 3), (1,)], [(0,), (3, 1), (2,)], [(0,), (3, 2), (1,)], [(1,), (0, 2), (3,)], [(1,), (0, 3), (2,)], [(1,), (2, 0), (3,)], [(1,), (2, 3), (0,)], [(1,), (3, 0), (2,)], [(1,), (3, 2), (0,)], [(2,), (0, 1), (3,)], [(2,), (0, 3), (1,)], [(2,), (1, 0), (3,)], [(2,), (1, 3), (0,)], [(2,), (3, 0), (1,)], [(2,), (3, 1), (0,)], [(3,), (0, 1), (2,)], [(3,), (0, 2), (1,)], [(3,), (1, 0), (2,)], [(3,), (1, 2), (0,)], [(3,), (2, 0), (1,)], [(3,), (2, 1), (0,)]]
```

Comment: Thank you Ajax, unfortunately it does not work un my python, I have an `IndexError` in the last line of code, it seems `c` is empty and calling `c[-1]` throws an exception

Comment: @NiSi Please post the input that is causing the error.

Comment: Sorry Ajax, my bad, wrong indentation of the last else (under the for instead of under the if). Thank you again